# Segmentation fault when trying to reverse a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning Common Lisp and I've been trying to write a function to reverse a list. This is the function but every time I try to run it I get "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)"

```
(defun reverseList(x)
  (if (cdr x)
      (cons (reverseList x) (car x))
    (car x)))


(reverseList '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: You got a stackoverflow (sic!) because your code calls `reverseList` with the same list infinitely. It's nonterminating.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I meant to pass it cdr x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
(define reverseList(lambda(x)(
                          if (null? (cdr x))
                             (cons (car x) '())
                             (append (reverseList (cdr x)) (cons (car x) '()))                                  
                             )
                 )
)
```